# Azure VM Logs and Azure Storage

Tags: c#, azure, cloud, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I need an advise about Azure services.
Suppose that I have a Linux VM in Azure with some application working there. This application generates some log files. I'm interesting in uploading these log files to a directory in Azure Storage. What is the best way to do it?. How about security?, would I do it without creating a public directory?.

Comment: This question is too broad. Here, you need to ask a specific question supported with some code etc

Comment: Azure storage has a security guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-security-guide

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to deal with this use case. I'll give you the simplest one. Under your storage account, create a file share, through Files, once you do, there will be an option to connect on top left, this will provide you with the specific commands to run on your vm in order to attach this file share. once this is done, point out the log files to be stored to that drive. From a security standpoint, you will be using unique keys to access that specific file share to protect access to it.
Step by step guide can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share